# java division of integers set precision

Tags: java, string

I have two ints

```
int a = 5324;
int b = 5;
```

Dividing "a" by "b" I should get answer as "1064.8". I want to convert this answer to string. I am expecting my string to be "1064.8". And I am interested in "8" that comes after "."

How do I make sure that my string will contain exactly 1 character after "."

Here is my try:

```
float answer = ((float) a)/b;
String s = answer.toString();
Character result = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
```

But, I am not able to make sure that my result is same as character after "."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just multiply your result by 10 so that the digit you're interested in is the last digit in the integer division result. Then you can use `% 10` to get the last base 10 digit:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5324;
    int b = 5;

    int fixedpointresult = 10*a/b;
    int lastDigit = fixedpointresult % 10;

    System.out.println(lastDigit);
  }
}
```

This prints 8

Comment: Of all the answers provided, this will be the fastest.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want to print the result with a precision of one.
`String.format()` offers support for this:

```
float answer = ((float) a)/b;    
String out = String.format("%.1f",answer);
```

Or you can use a `DecimalFormat`

```
  DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(""###.#"");
  String output = myFormatter.format(value);
```

Additional reference and examples are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

If you are really only interested in the first char behind the `.` That Other Guys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248734/3636680) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will give you the first number after the decimal point as char:

```
char result = Character.forDigit(int(((float)(a%b) / b) * 10), 10);
```

1. Get the modulo value: 4
2. Cast it to float and divide it by b: 0.8
3. Bring the desired number in front of the decimal point: 8.0
4. Cast it to int to cut off any rest (there is none in this case): 8
5. Convert it to char using [Character.forDigit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int))